# mysql.connector analogue to SQLAlchemy's pd.to_sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

While programming on Python and working with SQL dbs I previously used mysql.connector library, but I found out that it takes a lot of rows of code to get your data into SQL table because you need to write the whole SQL query column by column.
From the other side while using pandas there are easy methods working with SQLalchemy library only:
- pd.to_sql
- pd.read_sql_table
(Well, I got errors while using mysql db.cursor() and couldn't find any tutorial besides SQLalchemy + Pandas).
These two methods let you easily get a dataframe from SQL table and create a SQL table from dataframe.

**I wonder if there is such analogue in mysql.connector to easily convert dataframe to SQL table and vice versa, since still the syntax of this library for me is more convenient for other actions rather than SQL???**

> P.S. MySQL initiate code is written just for  info and not used in
>   provided code, though I need to somehow find an analogue

```
# ------------------- IMPORT -------------------------
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

# ------------------- MYSQL + SQL Alchemy -------------------------
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='host',
    user='user',
    passwd='pass',
    database='db'
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@host/db', pool_recycle=3600)

# ------------------- FUNCTIONS ----------------------
def get_function():
    df = pd.read_html(
        "https://www.url.com")
    df[3].to_sql(name=table, con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')


# -------------------- MAIN --------------------------
table = 'table_name'
get_function()
print(pd.read_sql_table(table, engine, columns=[]))
```

Comment: Check the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html). For `mysql+mysqldb` you need to use  [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/), not MySQL Connector/Python. Using MySQL Connector/Python is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, so I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but I'll try my best to answer.

So SQLAlchemy is a so called [Object-relational-Mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (like Hibernate in the Java world), which maps between relations (columns, rows, tables) and objects.

Pandas is a data analysis library, that can use SQLAlchemy. SQLAlchemy itself  [supports a wide range of Databases](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/index.html), including MySQL.

Now I didn't understand whether you'd like to use Pandas + SQLAlchemy + MySQL, or whether you just want a simple way to work with MySQL directly.
In the first case you can simply use Pandas, in the latter case you can use SQLAlchemy directly. [Pandas provides documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#sql-queries) and so does [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/index.html)

Comment: Currently I'm working with different dataframes parsed from web and for this purpose and also for data manipulation I use pandas library. Though I really need this functionality to write SQL tables from DFs and vice versa, but for this I need to initiate SQL Alchemy library, though I would like to use Pandas + MySQL.connector without SQL Alchemy - is this possible or not? Otherwise I need to inititae both mysql.connector to make queries and SQL Alchemy to read/write SQL tables to/from pandas dataframes.

Comment: @Dram I still don't understand. You are using Pandas and you have an active MySQL connection, but you don't want to use SQLAlchemy (why?)? Anyway, it seems that Pandas only supports SQLAlchemy. SQL queries are DB specific (in party), so Pandas would need code to generate SQL for a wide range of DBs, that's a lot of work and SQL Alchemy already does that.

Comment: Is it possible to just use pandas and the mysql.connector library without using sqlalchemy?

Comment: I think it should work. According to the Pandas docs, you just need a Python DB API compatible library and according to the mysql.connector docs, it is compliant with the Python Database API Specification v2.0 (PEP 249).